# Django(PySCADA) : HTML (code fed thru textbox) is not getting Value from Django

Tags: python, django, scada, html-injections

I have Text box at backend-admin where admin can add HTML code which is required for display on Users-Screens.

HTML code is getting executed but values of Django veriables are not fetched. (Please refer input & output screens)

[Input Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o4az.jpg)

[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjt8s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Following tag will return value in HTML from PySCADA

```
<span class="type-numeric var-aACB">NaN</span>
```

here, value of variable "aACB" is required to be displayed in HTML

https://cwraig.id.au/2017/09/24/pyscada-on-raspberry-pi-for-temperature-monitoring-with-ds18b20-on-1-wire-part-4-pyscada-hmi-configuration/amp/